# First Game: Simon Game

Tags: python, beginner, game, tkinter, simon-says

I am working on a Simon game using python and tkinter, just now it is incomplete, but I don't know if I am doing it right because it looks messy, and I would like to have a check on my code for corrections and suggestions on how to improve it.

This is the first game I'm making, and I don't have to much experience in programming.

This is my actual entire code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import random

base = Tkinter.Tk()

fr = Tkinter.Frame(base, bg="black", width="238", height="250")


score = Tkinter.Label(base, bg="black", fg="white", text="Score:")
score.place(x = 30, y = 15)

s = 0

scoreNum = Tkinter.Label(base, bg="black", fg="white", text = s)
scoreNum.place(x = 70, y = 15)


best = Tkinter.Label(base, bg="black", fg="white", text="Best:")
best.place(x = 155, y = 15)

b = 0

bestNum = Tkinter.Label(base, bg="black", fg="white", text = b)
bestNum.place(x = 188, y = 15)


clicks = []
color = 0

def yellowClick():

    yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow3")
    yellow.after(500, lambda: yellow.configure(activebackground="yellow"))

    global clicks
    global color

    color = 1
    clicks.append(color)

yellow = Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                       width="7", height="5", activebackground="yellow",  
                       bg="yellow3", command = yellowClick)

yellow.place(x = 30, y = 50)


def blueClick():

    blue.configure(activebackground="medium blue")
    blue.after(500, lambda: blue.configure(activebackground="blue"))

    global clicks
    global color

    color = 2
    clicks.append(color)

blue = Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                     width="7", height="5", activebackground="blue",
                     bg="medium blue", command = blueClick)

blue.place(x = 125, y = 50)


def redClick():

    red.configure(activebackground="red3")
    red.after(500, lambda: red.configure(activebackground="red"))

    global clicks
    global color 

    color = 3
    clicks.append(color)

red = Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                    width="7", height="5", activebackground="red",
                    bg = "red3", command = redClick)    

red.place(x = 30, y = 145)


def greenClick():

    green.configure(activebackground="dark green")
    green.after(500, lambda: green.configure(activebackground="green4"))

    global clicks
    global color

    color = 4
    clicks.append(color)

green = Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                      width="7", height="5", activebackground="green4",
                      bg="dark green", command = greenClick)

green.place(x = 125, y = 145)   


def scoreUp():

    global s

    s = s + 1

    scoreNum.configure(text = s)


r = random.randint(1, 4)

sequence = []

def checkSequence():

    global clicks
    global sequence

    if clicks == sequence:

        scoreUp()

def showSequence():

    global r
    global sequence

    if r == 1:

        yellow.configure(bg="yellow")
        yellow.after(1000, lambda: yellow.configure(bg="yellow3"))

        sequence.append(r)

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)

    elif r == 2:

        blue.configure(bg="blue")
        blue.after(1000, lambda: blue.configure(bg="medium blue"))  

        sequence.append(r)

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)

    elif r == 3:

        red.configure(bg="red")
        red.after(1000, lambda: red.configure(bg="red3"))   

        sequence.append(r)

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)

    elif r == 4:

        green.configure(bg="green4")
        green.after(1000, lambda: green.configure(bg="dark green")) 

        sequence.append(r)      

        base.after(5000, checkSequence)


base.after(2000, showSequence)

fr.pack()

base.resizable(False, False)
base.mainloop()
```

Actually I'm checking the sequence with time because I can't find another to do it.

Comment: Does this actually work as intended? Because for me it does not completely. While showing a sequence works, the validation of the user-entered sequence is not implemented (and therefore the score never gets updated).

Comment: That's why I said that it is not complete. I Only want to know if I'm writting it the right way.

Comment: Well, in that case, I will post my code suggestions later. There are a lot of improvements possible, but I didn't get it to completely work yet, myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has an official style-guide, PEP8, which you are encouraged to follow to improve readability (mostly by others, but also yourself). On e of its recommendations is using spaces around operators, but no spaces around `=` when assigning keywords. So these are *good*:

```
var = "value"
l = [2, 1, 3]
l.sort(reverse=True)
```

while these are *bad*:

```
var="value"
l=[ 1,2,3 ]
l.sort( reverse = True)
```

---

In general it is not best practice to use `global`, because it makes the state your program is in potentially undefined.

For example the function

```
def f():
    global c
    return c
```

It is not defined what this function will output at any given time, because anybody else might modify the global `c`.

Most of the times, `global` can be avoided entirely, just by making functions accept the values as parameters and returning the results where necessary.

In your case this is a bit more tricky, because many of these functions cannot take any parameter (because `Tkinter` just calls them as they are).

There is one work-around for it and one solution, though.

One is using lambdas, like this:

```
buttons = []
for i in range(10):
    buttons.append(Tkinter.Button(base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                               width="7", height="5", activebackground=color,
                               bg=alt_color, command=lambda i=i: print i)
```

Here the `i=i` is evaluated whenever the function is called. A simple `lambda: print i` would have failed.

The actual solution to this problem, though is to use a class. This way you can pack all those global variables as attributes, can access them within the functions, and so on.

I won't go into details about how to write a class, because there are very good tutorials about this (*add links*).

There are a few more noteworthy changes.

I made functions to create and place a label, which is pretty straight-forward, and to create and place a button. The latter is a bit more complicated, because, as explained above, the button needs a parameter-less function. For this I used the fact that in python functions are first-class objects. This means that you can return functions from other functions. I therefore wrote a button click handler factory, that produces a custom function given its parameters (with the right color, highlightcolor, etc).

To save the data of the different buttons I created a `collections.namedtuple`, which is just a tuple, where you can access the members also by name (but also still by index if you need to).

Then I made the game slightly more complete by adding a variable length of the shown sequence, an actual saving and verification of the user sequence and the correct handling of checking whether it is correct.

The attribute `self.sequence` contains the generated (and shown) sequence, while if a user clicks a button it is added to `self.user_sequence` if the two are identical the user wins, score is updated (and best if needed). A new sequence can be generated, with a length one longer than before.

If the user clicks and the sequence is right so far, nothing happens. But if the user clicks a button which is not the next in the sequence, the game resets (keeping only best).

I also placed the actual execution of the game in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard to allow importing parts of the code from other scripts (So you can e.g. do `from simon_game import Button`, if this code is saved as `simon_game.py`).

---

**Final code:**

```
import Tkinter
import random
from collections import namedtuple

Button = namedtuple("Button", "color alt_color x y")
BUTTONS_DATA = [Button("yellow", "yellow3", 30, 50),
                Button("blue", "medium blue", 125, 50),
                Button("red", "red3", 30, 145),
                Button("green", "dark green", 125, 145)]


class SimonGame:
    def __init__(self, buttons_data=BUTTONS_DATA):
        self.base = Tkinter.Tk()
        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(self.base, bg="black", width="238", height="250")

        self.score = 0
        self.score_label = self.place_label(30, 15, "Score:")
        self.score_val = self.place_label(70, 15, self.score)

        self.best = 0
        self.best_label = self.place_label(155, 15, "Best:")
        self.best_val = self.place_label(188, 15, self.best)

        self.start = Tkinter.Button(self.base, bd="0", text="start", command=self.show_sequence)
        self.start.place(x=90, y=12)

        self.sequence = []
        self.user_sequence = []

        self.buttons_data = buttons_data
        self.buttons = [self.create_button(*button) for button in self.buttons_data]

        self.frame.pack()
        self.base.resizable(False, False)
        self.base.mainloop()

    def place_label(self, x, y, text, fg="white", bg="black"):
        label = Tkinter.Label(self.base, bg=bg, fg=fg, text=text)
        label.place(x=x, y=y)
        return label

    def click_factory(self, button, color, alt_color):
        def click():
            button.configure(activebackground=alt_color)
            button.after(500, lambda: button.configure(activebackground=color))
            self.user_sequence.append(color)
            self.check_sequence()
        return click

    def create_button(self, color, alt_color, x, y):
        button = Tkinter.Button(self.base, bd="0", highlightthickness="0",
                           width="7", height="5", activebackground=color,
                           bg=alt_color)
        button['command'] = self.click_factory(button, color, alt_color)
        button.place(x=x, y=y)
        return button

    def show_sequence(self):
        self.reset_gui()
        for _ in range(self.score + 1):
            i = random.randrange(len(self.buttons))
            button = self.buttons[i]
            button_data = self.buttons_data[i]
            button.configure(bg=button_data.color)
            button.after(750, lambda: button.configure(bg=button_data.alt_color))
            self.sequence.append(button_data.color)
        print self.sequence

    def check_sequence(self):
        if self.sequence == self.user_sequence:
            self.score += 1
            self.best = max(self.best, self.score)
            self.reset_gui()
        elif not self.sequence[:len(self.user_sequence)] == self.user_sequence:
            self.score = 0
            self.reset_gui()

    def reset_gui(self):
        self.sequence = []
        self.user_sequence = []
        for button, data in zip(self.buttons, self.buttons_data):
            button.configure(bg=data.alt_color, activebackground=data.color)
        self.best_val.configure(text=self.best)
        self.score_val.configure(text=self.score)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = SimonGame()
```

---

What is left to do:
The graphical part is not very clean. Some buttons get stuck on on (in sequences where a button appears an even number of times) and the sequence plays out too fast. Also more visual feedback when getting a whole sequence right or messing it up would help.